# Can't Remove Listview Item From Second Form

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am having an issue when trying to delete ListView Items from a second form.

For example, if I use the following command on Form1 it works:

```
Listview1.SelectedItems(0).Remove
```

However, if I attempt to remove from Form2 like so:

```
Form1.Listview1.SelectedItems(0).Remove
```

I get the following error:
"Invalid argument=value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index"

I then tried to get a count of items from the listview on Form2 and it gives me a return of 0

```
Form1.Listview1.Items.Count
```

I'm not sure what my problem is.

**Update**

I have posted a brief example of my code (using your suggestion as I can understand it):

### frmShowMessages

```
Private Sub ViewMessage()
    Dim frm As New frmViewMailMessage
    frm.Show()
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteItem(ByVal index As Integer)
    lsvReceivedMessages.Items(index).Remove()
End Sub
```

### frmViewMessage

```
Private instanceForm as frmShowMessages

Private Sub frmViewMailMessage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    instanceForm = New frmShowMessages()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
    instanceForm.DeleteItem(_index)
End Sub
```

Hopefully my code can help identify where my issue is.

Comment: Could it be that `Form1` <> `Form2`

Comment: There are several ways to get yourself into trouble when you use a *type name* like "Form1" where an object reference is required.  Such as running this code on a worker thread, the most common mishap, that will create a new instance of the Form1 class and of course its ListView is empty.  Or having more than one instance of the form class, now of course it doesn't know which one to choose.  This weirdo syntax is supported in VB.NET to give VB6 programmers a fighting chance to switch.  It is however a very bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.net usually you get a default `Form` instance for each of your `Form`. Probably you are creating an instance of `Form1` and then you are trying to access `ListView1` of default instance.

E.g.

```
Sub ButtonClick()
    Dim f As New Form1()
    f.Show()
    ' at this point if you access f's ListView you will get correct count
    f.ListView1.Items.Count
    ' however if you try to access default instance it will NOT have any item
    Form1.ListView.Items.Count
End Sub
```

It means your instance `f` is NOT equal to default `Form1` instance.

Solution can be, make the `f` variable as class level variable and use it everywhere. Or if `Form1` will have only 1 instance, then you can use the default instance everywhere.

Personally I would NOT go with direct control accessing over forms. I would create a `Public` method which should return the data as list to the caller, in this case your `Form2`.

**UPDATED-2:**

As per your given scenario, I am simplifying things for you, and doing implementation using `Event`.

```
Public Class frmShowMessages

    Private Sub btnOpenMessage_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOpenMessage.Click
        Dim frmView As New frmViewMessage(Me.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Index)
        AddHandler frmView.MessageDeleted, AddressOf DeleteMessageHandler
        frmView.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteMessageHandler(sender As Object, e As frmViewMessage.MessageDeletedEventArgs)
        Me.ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(e.MessageIndex)
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class frmViewMessage
    ' a class which will be used for Event communication
    Public Class MessageDeletedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs

        Public Property MessageIndex As Integer

        Public Sub New(ByVal iIndex As Integer)
            MyBase.New()
            Me.MessageIndex = iIndex
        End Sub
    End Class

    ' main event which will alert the parent that a message deletion should be done
    Public Event MessageDeleted As EventHandler(Of MessageDeletedEventArgs)
    ' private variable that will hold the MessageIndex
    Private Property MessageIndex As Integer

    ' method that is responsible to raise event
    Protected Overridable Sub OnMessageDeleted()
        RaiseEvent MessageDeleted(Me, New MessageDeletedEventArgs(Me.MessageIndex))
    End Sub

    ' we want to create this Form using the MessageIndex of ListView
    Public Sub New(ByVal iMessageIndex As Integer)
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.MessageIndex = iMessageIndex
    End Sub

    ' the delete button will raise the event to indicate parent that
    ' a deletion of message should be done
    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Me.OnMessageDeleted()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks sallushan. That is exactly what I have done. Dim frm as new Form2()....frm.Show().  Then from form 2 I attempt Form1.Listview1.Items.Count.  I basically just want to delete a listview item from Form1 whilst in Form2.  I'm not sure I understand completely about creating a public method and returning data as a list??  Could you care to elaborate please.

Comment: Updated the answer, added an example for you

Comment: Sorry sallushan, I am still having issues getting my head around this properly. Your example shows the listview on Form1 and then calling Form1 from Form2 and then removing the item on Form1 from Form2.  Whereas, I need to call Form2 from Form1 but then remove a listview item on Form1 from Form2 which still isn't working.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Wow Sallushan, you are truly a saint!  Thankyou so much, your code worked a treat and you have provided a great example to allow me to learn from. I've never passed Events through forms before. Thankyou so much!